# Group consecutive dates on multiple occurrences of ID's as individual encounters

Tags: r, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Below is an example of the problem I have. Specifically I have a situation where there are multiple entries for the person ID's of consecutive date entries. I want to group these entries that are consecutive to show specific 'episodes.'

I have a table like this:

```
ID    DATE
A     11/16/2017
A     11/17/2017
A     11/18/2017
A     11/18/2017
B     11/12/2017
B     11/13/2017
B     11/14/2017
C     10/31/2017
C     10/31/2017
A     11/22/2017
A     11/22/2017
A     11/23/2017
```

And I would like the result table to be like this from this sample table

```
ID StartDATE  EndDATE
A    11/16/2017  11/18/2017
B    11/12/2017  11/14/2017
C    10/31/2017  10/31/2017
A    11/22/2017  11/23/2017
```

Comment: Guessing that mysql was added accidentally since the title says sql server

Comment: are you trying to do this using R or SQL?

Comment: Google `SQL gaps and islands` and you will find lots of examples.

Comment: I would like to do it in either SQL Server or R.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time researching gaps and islands and have not found a scenario like this one.

Comment: Ok, I googled it, clicked on the first result, and found a scenario exactly like this one:   https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/   The only difference is that his second column is an integer rather than a date, which doesn't affect the logic of the solution, only the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could do trick with row number with something like this:

```
select ID, min(DATE), max(DATE) from
(
  select *, datediff(day, RN, DATE) GRP
  from (
    select *, row_number () over (partition by ID order by DATE asc) as RN
    from (
      select distinct ID, DATE from Table1
    ) X
  ) Y
) Z
group by ID, GRP
```

This calculates the difference between the "day" of the row number and the date, and as long as the difference stays the same, it's a sequential date.

Comment: I think you could do away with the DISTINCT derived table if you use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't think about that. That should work and make it faster.

Comment: I like this trick.  At first I thought there must be a way to break it, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long-winded solution. First I detect consecutive groups and store it in the `grp` variable. Then, I split the data by ID, then apply a range function to each subset and make it pretty by creating a data.frame which holds ID and both dates. In the end, the `do.call` function just glues everything together.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "ID    DATE
A     11/16/2017
                 A     11/17/2017
                 A     11/18/2017
                 A     11/18/2017
                 B     11/12/2017
                 B     11/13/2017
                 B     11/14/2017
                 C     10/31/2017
                 C     10/31/2017
                 A     11/22/2017
                 A     11/22/2017
                 A     11/23/2017", header = TRUE)
xy$DATE <- as.Date(xy$DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
xy$grp <- cumsum(c(1, diff(as.numeric(as.factor(xy$ID))) != 0))

split.by.id <- split(xy, f = xy$grp)
run.by.id <- lapply(split.by.id, FUN = function(x) {
  rng <- range(x$DATE)
  data.frame(ID = unique(x$ID), StartDate = rng[1], EndDate = rng[2])
})
range.by.id <- do.call(rbind, run.by.id)
range.by.id

  ID  StartDate    EndDate
1  A 2017-11-16 2017-11-18
2  B 2017-11-12 2017-11-14
3  C 2017-10-31 2017-10-31
4  A 2017-11-22 2017-11-23
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the assistance!